# Windows codepage is broken

Tags: windows-7, character-encoding, locale

My Windows installation has Latin and Cyrillic inputs enabled, but uses the English layout.

And I suddenly realized that non-unicode programs can not display Cyrillic symbols.  They are displayed as `?`.

So it seems that my codepage became broken or something... I believe it should be `Windows-1251`. But I don't know/remeber is there a global codepage settings? Maybe somewere in registry? I would prefer to not reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything else fails, you can try to dive into

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage

- ACP is the default ANSI code page
- OEMCP is the default OEM code page
- MACCP is the default Macintosh code page

Answer (score 1):

> **is there a global codepage settings exist?**

`Start` -> `Control Panel` -> `Clock, Language and Region` ->  `Region and Language`

Choose the `Administrative` tab, there is a section subtitled `Language for non-unicode programs`, click the <kbd>Change System Locale …</kbd> button.

> The system locale determines the default character set (letters, symbols, and numbers) and font used to enter and display information in programs that don't use Unicode. This allows non-Unicode programs to run on your computer using the specified language. You might need to change the default system locale when you install additional display languages on your computer. Selecting a different language for the system locale doesn't affect the language in menus and dialog boxes for Windows or other programs that do use Unicode